# Objective C--Assign C array to instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, pointers

I am building a class to make displaying 3d objects with OpenGl ES easier. I have two main methods in the class; `-(void)setUpWithVerticeArray:(float*)verticeArray withIndiceArray:(short*)faceIndiceArray` and `-(void)render`. In `setUpWithVerticeArray: withIndiceArray` I want to set instance variables be to pointers of the arrays passed in so I can use them the `render` method. How can I do this? I've been trying to do this:

```
@interface BRObject(){
float *_sourceVertices;
short *_faceIndices;
}
...
-(void)setUpWithVerticeArray:(float*)verticeArray withIndiceArray:(short*)faceIndiceArray{

_sourceVertices = verticeArray;
_faceIndices = faceIndiceArray;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

The debugger displays this on the breakpoints:

[image]

-1.00013995 is an acceptable value for the first entry in the array.

Comment: Can you define 'not working'? Does it compile ?

Comment: It does, but the model doesn't display. I know that sounds as though it could have any number of problems, but if I replace all the places where the ivars are used with the const arrays it renders.

Comment: Have you used the debugger in places where your code uses or handles the array to see what you are actually dealing with? That could produce some useful information which you could report in the question. For now voting to hold while waiting for more information.

Comment: I have used the debugger. What it shows is the first value that should be in the array, but nothing else.

Comment: just curious, when you actually use these arrays (in render, I guess) how do you determine their length? The debugger doesn't know they are arrays, just pointers to float and short, so I'm not surprised at what it displays. But that doesn't mean the code couldn't work...

Comment: It's a C array, the first element being the value at the pointer seems perfectly correct.

Comment: @RobP by using the `sizeOf()` function

Comment: 1) Are the breakpoint results in your questions inside the function or outside? Can you test both and make sure output match? 2) Are you using ARC?

Comment: It sounds as if you might have an easier time if you used NSArray.

Comment: NSArray is a very big performance hit, I've profiled the heck out of it. I'm guessing this code is performance-sensitive. I still don't understand how you get the length of the arrays, sizeOf what exactly?

Comment: So far you haven't described a problem.

Comment: @RobP - Do one UI operation and it doesn't matter whether you used an NSArray or a C array.

Comment: @HotLicks I had an app that ran an NP-complete algorithm on a large data set, and on an iPhone 4s it took 2 minutes. I profiled it and ~99% of the time was spent on overhead for NSFoundation classes. I changed to base C types and got the operation to about 1 second with no other changes.

Comment: @RobP - And how many UI operations did you do in that time period?

Comment: what's your point? the UI remained responsive during the background calculation, but the user was still waiting for it to complete, so performance mattered.

Comment: @HotLicks My problem is that I don't know how to set a instance variable of the class to the array that is passed as a parameter to the function above. If it were an NSArray I would do `_myArrayIVar = verticeArray`, but I want to save on performance by using a C array.

Comment: If you do sizeOf(faceIndices) where faceIndices is a short*, you're likely to always get 4 or 8 bytes no matter how big the array is.   sizeOf pretty much only works for staticly allocated arrays.

Comment: The instance variable can only ever be a `something*`.

Comment: (Understand that C arrays are not objects.  In fact, C arrays are something of a fiction.)

Comment: I found the issue. I needed to store the amount of elements of the array in an instance variable to call `glDrawElements(...)` in `-render`.  When I called it before I passed in an int which I thought was the amount of indices in the array, but I was wrong. I apologize for overlooking this.